# Django Session Variables Don't Work In Stripe Webhook?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am trying to use data saved in `django session variables` to run a function once the webhook has confirmed that `'checkout.session.completed'` but I always get a key error. I am 100% sure the keys exist in the session variables.

Here is my webhook:

```
@csrf_exempt
def stripe_webhook(request):

    # You can find your endpoint's secret in your webhook settings
    endpoint_secret = 'secret'

    payload = request.body
    sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = None

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    # Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        session = event['data']['object']
        fulfull_order(session)


    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Here is my fulfill order function:

```
def fulfull_order(session):

 generator = PlanMaker(goal=request.session['goal'], gender=request.session['gender'])

  /// send email code.
```

This line `generator = PlanMaker(goal=request.session['goal'], gender=request.session['gender'])`

Always gives a key error on `request.session['goal']` The key definitely exists, it just seems it is inaccessible from the webhook view.

How to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save the information you want to the `metadata` field when creating the `checkout.Session`.

```
def checkout(request):
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
            'price': 'price_key',
            'quantity': 1,
        }],
        mode='payment',
        success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('success_url')) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancel_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('cancel_url')),
        metadata={'someKeyHere': 'your session variable data'}
    )

    return JsonResponse({
        'session_id' : session.id,
        'stripe_public_key' : settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    })
```

then you can access the information like `session['metadata']['someKeyHere']`

Answer (score 1):

The webhook event is a separate request coming directly from Stripe that would not be related to any Django session and so this lack of session data would seem expected. As @Anthony suggests you can store this information in the Checkout Session metadata when you create the session. The `metadata` will be included in the webhook object.